# how to create a service that monitors data related to CPU Status, Memory Usage etc

Tags: android, memory, cpu

I want to know if we can create a background app (non UI) which monitors data related to systems CPU Status, Memory Usage, Disk Space, Installed Apps using services/BR in android. I know its not possible in iOS not sure about android though. There are many foreground (with UI) apps in the market which has these functionalities.

Please let me know if its possible and if yes how?

Comment: Not tried anything specific till now.. Just searching over the web if we can actually do it..